# iphone - Access to variables of loop generated objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, loops, parameters

I want to create a Chess game with a Field. In the code I created first the Chessboard via Loop.

```
-(void)CreateGame{

NSMutableArray* Board = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++) {

        for (int y = 1; y <= 9; y++) {
            MainGame* Boardfield = [[MainGame alloc] initBoardWithInt:x*10+y State:0];
            [Boardfield.view setFrame:CGRectMake(300 +x*65-60, 30 +y*65-60, 60, 60)];
            UITapGestureRecognizer* FieldTouch = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ClickedPawn:)];
            [Boardfield.view addGestureRecognizer:FieldTouch];
            FieldTouch.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

            Boardfield.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

            [self.view addSubview:Boardfield.view];
            [Boardfield.view setTag:x*10+y];
            [Board addObject:Boardfield];
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Init Action:

```
-(id)initBoardWithInt:(int)Location State:(int)Property{
    self = [super init];

    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    Location = Loc;
    Property = ID;
    return self;
}
```

Location is the Property the Location of a Field in the Chessboard and State is the ID of the Figure that stands on it (0 means none).

Now I want to get Access to the Object with the Tap Gesture Recognizer or with the tag number. Is there any way to get the active MainGame* Object created by the loop?

Comment: The gesture recognizer action can take a single parameter, which will be the gesture recognizer that fired.  Gesture recognizer has a `.view` property that is the view to which it is attached.  You may also opt to assign that view a tag corresponding to an array index.  (but make it index + somePositiveInt because tag==0 is the default value and might be confused with other views.

Comment: I know, but i dont have problems with tags. The second problem is, that the action, i which CreateGame is called, always loops. Even if I put it in predefined actions like ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear, it loops forever. I think, its a bug....